# Get RequestId in a custom python logger to use in AWS-Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to find a mechanism to specify a custom logger without losing the RequestId value provided by default in AWS Lambda.

I was able to modify and customize the properties of the recordlog in the following way:

```
class PackagePathFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.relativepath = ''
        if record.pathname is not None:
            record.relativepath = record.pathname.replace('/var/task','')
        return True


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addFilter(PackagePathFilter())
FORMAT = "[%(levelname)s] [%(requestId)s] [%(relativepath)s:%(lineno)d] [%(funcName)s] - %(message)s"
formatter = logging.Formatter(FORMAT)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

The only thing I'm missing from my ideal format is the RequestId.

Comment: Maybe this link may be helpful https://gist.github.com/niranjv/fb95e716151642e8ca553b0e38dd152e

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can retain the default lambda logger and override it's formatting:

```
import logging

root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.INFO)

for handler in root.handlers:
    handler.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter(
            fmt="[%(levelname)s]\t%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03dZ\t%(aws_request_id)s\t%(message)s\n",
            datefmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",
        )
    )
```

You get access to the `aws_request_id` since it is made available via the `LambdaLoggerFilter` on the default logger.

Reference to AWS Lambda logging bootstrap:
https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-python-runtime-interface-client/blob/2.0.8/awslambdaric/bootstrap.py#L448-L451

If you want a ready-to-go example, here is a gist:
https://gist.github.com/matthewpick/3aa01abfeda36eae717837a99994d3ed